# Two slightly different polynomial expansions for $\Xi(0)$. Could a connection between these two be derived?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, orthogonal-polynomials

After experimenting with polynomial expansions for the Riemann $\Xi(t)=\xi\left(\frac12+it\right)$-function, I landed on these two equations:

[image]

with $M$ the [KummerM confluent hypergeometric funcion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function) and $L$ the [generalised Laguerre polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomials).

Both equations are equal except for the square in the parameter of $\Xi(x)$.

**Question (probably far fetched):**

Could it be possible to derive some relation between $\Xi(x^2)$ and $\Xi(x)$ from these equations?

P.S.
A similar set of equations exists for $\Xi(1)$.